Hit curb and plastic bumper partially popped out - Toyota Sienna 2025
My wife isn't used to the low body of the new 2025 Toyote sienna and hit the curb. Here a Re pictures of how the bumper disconnected. How do I go about getting it back in its place?




Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
